# Cannot Find Two Names in a Text File

Tags: visual-c++

I have a text file that contains 1000 lines.  The first line looks like this "1 Jacob Emily".  Lines 2-1000 are like that.  I need to write a program that calls a function that searches for the male name and female name.

My output should look like this:

For example, if the user enters the name “Justice” then the program should output:

```
Justice is ranked 406 in popularity among boys.
Justice is ranked 497 in popularity among girls.
```

If the user enters the name “Walter” then the program should output:

```
Walter is ranked 366 in popularity among boys.
Walter is not ranked among the top 1000 girl names.
```

Here is my function to search for the names:

```
void name_search (string name)
{
    int rank;
    string male, female; 
    ifstream infile;
    bool male_found = false, female_found = false;


    infile.open ("babynames2004.txt");

    if (infile.fail())
    {
        cout << "The file was corrupt.\n";
    }


    while (!infile.eof() && male_found == false && female_found == false)
    {
        infile >> rank >> male >> female;

        if (name == male)
            male_found=true;
        else if (name == female)
            female_found=true;
    }

    if(male_found == true && female_found != true)
    {
        cout << name << " is ranked " << rank << " in popularity among boys.\n";
        cout << name << " is not ranked among the top 1000 girl names.\n";
    }
    else if (male_found != true && female_found == true)
    {
        cout << name << " is not ranked among the top 1000 boys names.\n";
        cout << name << " is ranked " << rank << " in popularity among girls.\n";
    }
    else if (male_found == true && female_found == true)
    {
        cout << name << " is ranked " << rank << " in popularity among boys.\n";
        cout << name << " is ranked " << rank << " in popularity among girls.\n";
    }
    else if (male_found != true && female_found != true)
    {
        cout << name << " is not ranked among the top 1000 boys names.\n";
        cout << name << " is not ranked among the top 1000 girl names.\n";
    }

    infile.close();
}
```

Here is the output from the program that that function is called in (for lack of a better sentence).

```
This program allows you to search for the rank of a name from a list of the 1000
```

most popular male and female baby names of 2004.

Enter the name you would like to search for: Jacob
Jacob is ranked 1 in popularity among boys.
Jacob is not ranked among the top 1000 girl names.

Would you like to run this program again? (y or n)
y
This program allows you to search for the rank of a name from a list of the 1000
 most popular male and female baby names of 2004.

Enter the name you would like to search for: Emily
Emily is not ranked among the top 1000 boys names.
Emily is ranked 1 in popularity among girls.

Would you like to run this program again? (y or n)
y
This program allows you to search for the rank of a name from a list of the 1000
 most popular male and female baby names of 2004.

Enter the name you would like to search for: Jordan
Jordan is ranked 43 in popularity among boys.
Jordan is not ranked among the top 1000 girl names.

Would you like to run this program again? (y or n)

The name Jordan occurs on line 43 for males and line 70 for females.  The problem seems to be that when the output is wrong when the name occurs for both a male name and a female name.  by the way, this is an assignment for a programming class and the class is like a game.  It's not about actually learning to program, so I'm limited to only basic constructs that were taught in class.

Can anybody tell me why that is?

Comment: what is your question besides "can you do my work for me"

Comment: 1. Have user enter a name. 2. Create function that attaches to a text file and searches for a name match for either a male name, female name, or both.  Tell user if the name is in the top 1000 baby names for a male, female, both, or neither.  I'm been working on this for hours and posted for help over on cplusplus.  The class is a joke. I'm so limited it makes the code very hard to create.  I would use other constructs to solve the problem hours ago, but I'm basically not allowed because more advanced stuff was not covered in class.